# how to invoke rest api with domain object parameter

Tags: isis

I wrote a service action look like

```
@DomainService(
        nature = NatureOfService.VIEW_REST_ONLY,
        objectType = "rest.oneService"
)
onepackage.OneService{
   @Action(semantics = SemanticsOf.SAFE)
   public List<Data> findDataByPerson(Person person, LocalDate start, LocalDate end){
   ...
   }
}
```

In SwaggerUI is exposed as

```
get /services/rest.oneService/actions/findDataByPerson/invoke
```

I cannot find how to send domain objects as parameters to rest api;

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

References to domain objects use this format:

```
{
  "person": {
    "value": {
      "href": "http://~/objects/person.Person/123"
    }
  }
}
```

where `person.Person` is the object type (as per @DomainObject(objectType=...)) of the referenced type.

If invoking an action with a PUT (@Action(semantics=IDEMPOTENT)) or POST (@Action(semantics=NON_IDEMPOTENT)), then the above would be the body.

If invoking with a GET (@Action(semantics=SAFE)) then that json would need to be URL encoded and appended.

Further details in section 2.10 of the spec, also available online [here](https://www.restfulobjects.org/spec/1.0/section-a/chapter-02.html#2.10-passing-arguments-to-resources)

Comment: It can not work. My isis version is 1.16.2. As doc http://isis.apache.org/versions/1.16.2/guides/ugvro/ugvro.html#_invoking_a_get_link_eg_invoking_a_query_action It seems only work for scalar value. Thank you Dan.

Comment: I don't think that section says anything about whether reference parameters (as opposed to value parameters) work or not... it was just a demonstration of the latter.  Have you tried out the example?  This should work in 1.16.2 as well as 2.0.x ....  at least, I don't recall making a fix.

Comment: Thanks to @Dan Haywood help, I have tried out the correct calling method. Just change ref to href in above instructions. For the call of SemanticsOf.SAFE, the parameters need to be assigned to x-isis-querystring.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, James.  I'll update the answer for that typo.